# Undefined index value for radio button IN ajax php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am having a problem of getting value of my radio button I passed to data using ajax. Please help me to identify the problem I got into. Here's my code for:

HTML AJAX

```
<form method="post" id="upload_form">  
   <input type="radio" id="kindOfFile" name="kindOfFile" value="download" checked />Download
   <input type="radio" id="kindOfFile" name="kindOfFile" value="upload"/>Upload
   <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-lg">Upload Files</button>                     
</form>                 
<div id="val"></div>

<script>  
 $(document).ready(function(){   
      $('#upload_form').on('submit', function(e){  
        e.preventDefault();  
        //var formData = new FormData(this);
        var radioVal = $('input[type="radio"]:checked').val(); 

        $.ajax({  
            url :"processUpload.php",  
            method:"POST",
            data: { 'kindOfFile' : radioVal },  
            contentType:false,  
            processData:false,  
            success:function(data){  
                alert(data);
                $("#val").html(data);
            }  
        });
        return false;
      });  
 });  
 </script>
```

PHP:

```
$kindOfFile     = isset($_POST['kindOfFile']) ? $_POST['kindOfFile']: '';
print_r($kindOfFile); die();
```

Comment: Need more info than this, where exactly is the error occurring? What SPECIFIC error messages are you receiving? Also as of PHP 7 you can just do this: `$kindOfFile = $_POST['kindOfFile'] ?? '';`

Comment: specifically I got an error from PHP, because I think the data values from AJAX doesn't have value.

Comment: but when I alert the radioVal, there's a value, but when I alert inside the success , and alerted the data, I got an error from php. Undefined index for the kindOfFile

Answer (score 1):

Add a class name to all your your radio inputs :

```
 <input type="radio" class="radioInputsClass" id="kindOfFile" name="kindOfFile" value="download" checked />Download
<input type="radio" class="radioInputsClass" id="kindOfFile" name="kindOfFile" value="upload"/>Upload
```

and get the value of selected radio input using this :

```
var radioVal = $(".radioInputsClass:checked").val();
```

UPDATE :

Then, Change your data in your AJAX to :

```
data: JSON.stringify({'kindOfFile' : radioVal})
```

and also add :

```
dataType: "json",
contentType: 'application/json'
```

to your ajax call

Finally, in your php get the value like this :

```
$data = $_POST['data'];
$arr = json_decode($data, true);
```

Then you can access to value like :

```
print_r($arr['kindOfFile']); die();
```

Comment: still I got the undefined index from php

Answer (score 0):

If you set contentType and processData to false,you must use `FormData` [see documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) .Also `method` is not part of `ajax` ,if you want to set send method use `type`

```
<script>  
 $(document).ready(function(){   
      $('#upload_form').on('submit', function(e){  
        e.preventDefault();  
        var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);

        $.ajax({  
            url :"processUpload.php",  
            type:"POST",
            data: formData,  
            contentType:false,  
            processData:false,  
            success:function(data){  
                alert(data);
                $("#val").html(data);
            }  
        });
        return false;
      });  
 });  
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

@Janine Laude their are different methods of fetching the data from `<form>` in jquery few of them are explained here.

Firstly you are using `radio button` inside `<form>` .
Here below are the different methods of sending data.

HTML code:

```
<div class="container">
    <form method="post" id="upload_form">  
       <input type="radio" id="kindOfFile" name="kindOfFile" value="download" checked />Download
       <input type="radio" id="kindOfFile" name="kindOfFile" value="upload"/>Upload
       <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-lg">Upload Files</button>                     
    </form>                 
    <div id="val"></div>
</div>
```

`PHP` code:

```
    <?php
    $kindOfFile = $_POST['kindOfFile'];

    //YOU CAN CREAT A ARRAY AND SEND THORUGH JSON
    $Arr = array(
        'data'=>$kindOfFile,
    );

    //YOU CAN SEND THORUGH ARRAY
    // OR
    // YOU CAN JUST echo json_encode($kindOfFile);
    echo json_encode($Arr); //THIS IS PREFERED WHEN ARRAY WITH MORE INDEX TO BE SENT BACK
?>
```

JQUERY SCRIPT SENDING DATA WITH `FORM-DATA` AND RECEIVED `JSON`

```
 <script>  
 $(document).ready(function(){   
      $('#upload_form').on('submit', function(e){  
        e.preventDefault();  
        var formData = new FormData(this);

        $.ajax({  
            url :"processUpload.php",  
            method:"POST",
            data: formData,  
            contentType:false,  
            processData:false,  
            success:function(res){  
                var result = JSON.parse(res);
                //console.log(result.data);
                $("#val").html(result.data);
            }   
        });
        return false;
      });  
 });  
 </script>
```

JQUERY SCRIPT SENDING DATA WITH `serialize()` AND RECEIVED `JSON`

```
$('#upload_form').on('submit', function(e){  
    e.preventDefault();  
    var formSerialize = $(this).serialize();
    alert(formSerialize);
    $.ajax({  
        url :"processUpload.php",  
        method:"POST",
        data: formSerialize,   
        success:function(res){  
            var result = JSON.parse(res);
            //console.log(result.data);
            $("#val").html(result.data);
        }   
    });
    return false;
  });
```